# Why is Reachability connectionRequired important and why is it required?

Tags: ios, reachability

Why is Reachability connectionRequired important and why is it required?

i have some old code using connectionrequired like below:

```
BOOL connectionRequired= [curReach connectionRequired];
```

My question is why do we need to check above
and connection required by what?
the host/server or user/phone etc ?

Comment: What does the connectionRequired variable mean in the Reachability.h class that Apple wrote? In plain English?   //WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
//WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
- (BOOL) connectionRequired;